# Why is my bootstrap table not collapsing when everything seems in order?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a project and one of the things I would like to do is create a bootstrap table that can collapse and show with the click of a button. The problem is: it does neither. I checked to be sure that my javascript was in order, then proceeded to grab a bootstrap example from the website.

I tried it out and the example worked fine, but for some reason my table refuses to collapse.

Code:

Assignments tab

```html
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="lopendeopdrachten" colspan="10">Opdrachten 
                        <a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#currentassignmentdetails" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="" style="float: right; color: #1d68a7;">
                            <i class="fas fa-caret-square-up" style="float: right;"></i>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <div class="collapse" id="currentassignmentdetails">
                    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
                        <td>J. JANSEN<td>
                        <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
                        <td>TEAM 1<td>
                        <td>DICK<td>
                        <td>1/5/2020<td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
                        <td>J. JANSEN<td>
                        <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
                        <td>TEAM 1<td>
                        <td>DICK<td>
                        <td>1/5/2020<td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
                        <td>J. JANSEN<td>
                        <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
                        <td>TEAM 1<td>
                        <td>DICK<td>
                        <td>1/5/2020<td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="temporaryassignment">
                        <td>J. JANSEN<td>
                        <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
                        <td>TEAM 1<td>
                        <td>DICK<td>
                        <td>1/5/2020<td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

App.blade.php (main template for all pages)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- Sets the project title to the app name, if none is set it defaults to Laravel -->
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Style icons -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c3cdc1c42a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" >
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @include('inc.navbar')
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know the indenting is messy, sorry about that. If anyone could tell me where the particular error could be, that would be amazing. I double checked if both IDs matched (typo's and all) and I wrapped a div around it as the site said I should, but sadly nothing happened which is kinda weird in my opinion.

Bootstrap article reference link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/#example

If I forgot anything, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like markup you have is a little wonky in places like in the toggle button/link and where you placed the wrapper DIV. See if this does the trick. I'd also recommend shying away from the inline styles and move it into a separate CSS file - if you can.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#currentassignmentdetails" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Toggle Table</a>


<div class="collapse" id="currentassignmentdetails">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="lopendeopdrachten" colspan="10">Opdrachten</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
      <td>J. JANSEN<td>
      <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
      <td>TEAM 1<td>
      <td>DICK<td>
      <td>1/5/2020<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
      <td>J. JANSEN<td>
      <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
      <td>TEAM 1<td>
      <td>DICK<td>
      <td>1/5/2020<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
      <td>J. JANSEN<td>
      <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
      <td>TEAM 1<td>
      <td>DICK<td>
      <td>1/5/2020<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="temporaryassignment">
      <td>J. JANSEN<td>
      <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
      <td>TEAM 1<td>
      <td>DICK<td>
      <td>1/5/2020<td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    color:#1d68a7;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

And if you were looking to have the table header show all the time and just toggle the table rows/cells, you'll need to break it into two tables. It looks like you can't place a collapsible DIV in the middle of a table (just a guess, not sure why).

**HTML - Show header all the time**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="lopendeopdrachten" colspan="10">Opdrachten</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<div class="collapse" id="currentassignmentdetails">

<table class="table">  
  <tbody>
    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
      <td>J. JANSEN<td>
      <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
      <td>TEAM 1<td>
      <td>DICK<td>
      <td>1/5/2020<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
      <td>J. JANSEN<td>
      <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
      <td>TEAM 1<td>
      <td>DICK<td>
      <td>1/5/2020<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="assignmentdetails">
      <td>J. JANSEN<td>
      <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
      <td>TEAM 1<td>
      <td>DICK<td>
      <td>1/5/2020<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="temporaryassignment">
      <td>J. JANSEN<td>
      <td>JAARDOSSIER 2019<td>
      <td>TEAM 1<td>
      <td>DICK<td>
      <td>1/5/2020<td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: I agree. I would love to do it in the designated stylesheet, except referencing the icon class is a hassle and it is just an outright pain to move it over.

I will try out both of your recommendations and get back to you

Comment: Okay so I tried it out, it works perfectly. However now the next problem arises. The script I have to use (bootstrap JS) essentially breaks the dropdown links. With break I mean to say they stop working, they don't show the dropdown items etc. When I removed this script everything worked fine again besides the toggle.

Comment: Are you able to post/link your markup? It'd be easier to try and replicate it if it's available to look at.

Comment: There's not much to see. All I really have right now is the newly added bootstrap JS that both works and breaks at the same time, along with the toggle buttons. Other than that not much problems. I'll edit it in though

Comment: I'm sorry, are you saying that `<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` is breaking another element on the page besides the original toggle element? Or is it something different?

Comment: Yes. The bootstrap JS script breaks the dropdown menu. I cannot click and the link wont work either. It wont reveal the contents of the dropdown when I click it. I tested this out and it only occurred when implementing the bootstrap javascript library (the script)